# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - JSON character encoding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

In my controller I handle POST requests with ajax and adds data from GET requests directly to the js-code

mycontroller.php

```
$sServiceNumber = isset($_POST['ServiceNumber']) ? $_POST['ServiceNumber'] :  $_GET['ServiceNumber'];

//Here I do a db call for sServiceNumber and fetch some data as array $aAllrows

$aResponse['ServiceNumber'] = $sServiceNumber;
$aResponse['Data'] = $aAllrows;
$sJson = json_encode(self::convertToStrictUtf8($aResponse));

if (isset($_POST['ServiceNumber'])) {
    echo $sJson;
    exit;
} else {
    $sJs = '
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sData = \'' . $sJson . '\';
        handleResponseData(sData);
    });';

    MyHtmlHead::addExtraJsCode($sJs);

    //continue with rendering html page here..
}
```

When I call this with ajax everything works fine but when I try to run `handleResponseData()` directly I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` on special characters.

My JavaScript

```
function handleResponseData ( rawData ) {
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(rawData);  //<--this is where the error occurs (on GET requests)

    //Make use of response data
}

$("form[name='searchform']").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // Send post and fetch some data!
    $.post(baseUrl, { ServiceNumber: $("input[name='ServiceNumber']").val(), time: "2pm" }).done(handleResponseData);
});
```

Lastly here comes my conversion method

```
protected static function convertToStrictUtf8 ($p_aValues) {
    function detectEncoding(&$mValue) {
        if (!mb_detect_encoding($mValue, 'UTF-8', true)) {
            $mValue = utf8_encode($mValue);
        }
    }
    array_walk_recursive($p_aValues, 'detectEncoding');

    return $p_aValues;
}
```

How come the json string parses fine when fetched with jquery `$.post` but not when embedded into code manually? How do I solve this issue?

**edit**:
Stripped down version of rawData from `console.log(rawData)`

GET

```
{"ServiceNumber":"485218-1138932068","Data":[{"RowId":"AEEA-IU3A61","ServiceRequestId":"AEEA-IU39LX","Name":"SV LIDEHÄLL)","FileSize":"8812","ServiceNumber":"485218-1138932068","Subject":"O(BERGMAN/LIDEHÄLL)
","Area":"svrT","Dir":"1702"}]}
```

POST

```
{"ServiceNumber":"485218-1138932068","Data":[{"RowId":"AEEA-IU3A61","ServiceRequestId":"AEEA-IU39LX","Name":"SV LIDEH\u00c4LL)","FileSize":"8812","ServiceNumber":"485218-1138932068","Subject":"O(BERGMAN\/LIDEH\u00c4LL)\r\n","Area":"svrT","Dir":"1702"}]}
```

Comment: Post the rawdata. There is a parse error

Comment: Updated post. Yes, there is a parse error. But why?

Comment: As you can see, your json data differs.

Comment: @TimDev Yes ofc. Otherwise it would have worked ;) but why does it differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by `Line breaks` .

As the [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) docs states: "control characters" such as a tab or newline is not allowed.

When calling with `$.post` the new line chars were converted to a string `"\r\n"` which is why that case was working.

Adding something like this to remove new lines finally solved it.

```
function stripNewLines(&$mValue) {
    if(is_string($mValue)) {
        $mValue = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $mValue));
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($aResponse, 'stripNewLines');
```

Answer (score -1):

In your PHP controller, before echo JSON respose type the following line

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

and also in jQuery Ajax call you need to mention data type as JSON

```
$.ajax({
 ...,
 ...,
 dataType: 'JSON', // it is necessary to get JSON response 
 ...
});
```

Comment: `dataType: 'JSON',` is only necessary is the server lies about the content-type (which `header("Content-Type: application/json");` fixes).

Comment: This is not the issue. Also, the $.ajax call works fine if you read the question.